# 'array.reduce()' function unrecognised

Tags: javascript

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: data.reduce is not a function` and is shown to appear on the commented line here:

```
function stdDev(values) {
    var avg = average(values);
    var squareDiffs = values.map((value) => {
        return (value - avg) * (value - avg);
    });
    return Math.sqrt(average(squareDiffs));
}
function average(data) {
    var sum = data.reduce((sum, value) => {//this is the line in question
        return sum + value;
    });
    return sum / data.length;
}
$("#std").html(stdDev(12,21,32,34,18,26));
```

This code resides within a `<script>` tag in a `.ejs` document. I have no idea why a standard function would not be available, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check that `squareDiffs;` is, in fact, returning an array.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know it is not returning an array, and it meant to return a single value.

Comment: Well, there you go. `squareDiffs` is being passed to the `average` function as `data` and `data` is what you are then calling `reduce` on. If `squareDiffs` isn't an array, you can't call array methods on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the values into an array in the call to `stdDev`

```
$("#std").html(stdDev([12,21,32,34,18,26]));
```

Comment: Wow that was a stupid oversight by me, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Array.reduce works on array, it seems you are passing an object instead of an array,

change your method calling code as,

```
$("#std").html(stdDev([12,21,32,34,18,26]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You pass the numbers as a series of parameters, and not as an array. The `values`  is actually the 1st number you've passed, and not an array. Use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to collect all numbers to an array:

```js
function stdDev(...values) {
    const avg = average(values);
    const squareDiffs = values.map((value) => (value - avg) * (value - avg));
    return Math.sqrt(average(squareDiffs));
}

function average(data) {
    const sum = data.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value);
    return sum / data.length;
}

console.log(stdDev(12,21,32,34,18,26));
```

Answer (score 2):

you call `stdDev` with a list of numbers:

```
stdDev(12,21,32,34,18,26)
```

but the declaration expects an array:

```
function stdDev(values) {
```

so when you call

```
var avg = average(values);
```

you're passing `12`, which is not an array.